# ng-click() in a div behind another div

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to trigger ng-click in a div which is behind another div, and it is not working. Currently I have the situation as below:

[image]

In this situation, I want to trigger ng-click on yellow circle when it was clicked, but I have another div above the yellow circle, which is the div with folded corner image. How can I trigger ng-click() in div container of the yellow circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an empty span element to attach the event

```
<div class="green-box">
  <span class="yellow-number" ng-click="action()"></span>
</div>
```

Adding some css with green-box position relative and span.yellow-number with positions absolute.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @diegochavez :)